# Pyinstaller PyQt4 QAction error

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyinstaller

When I tried to create a onefile exe with my pyqt4 app I have 4 scripts that make up the whole thing. I have created the one exe but when I execute the file i get from the traceback

```
file "<string>" line 172 in <module>
file "<string>" line 33 in __init__
AttributeError: 'QAction' object has no attribute 'activated'
```

Not sure what I might be missing. I have followed the pyinstaller documentation. Any help is highly appreciated.

I have these lines calling activated

```
self.ui.actionExport_Database.activated.connect(self.dbexport)
self.ui.actionExport_Entire_Database.activated.connect(self.dbexportall)
self.ui.actionClose.activated.connect(self.close)
```

The command I used for the exe was

```
python pyinstaller.py --onefile yourprogram.pyw
python pyinstaller.py --onefile your-program.spec
```

not sure if I should have waited till the second command to use the onefile option.

Comment: Can you show the part of your code that causes this error? And the PyInstaller command you used?

Comment: updated the original post with the missing info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the same error also occurs when you run the script instead of the binary, and that the problem is therefore unrelated to PyInstaller.

Because it looks like `self.ui.actionExport_Database` etc. are [QAction](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qaction.html) instances, which indeed have no attribute `activated`. You probably meant `triggered`:

> This signal is emitted when an action is activated by the user; for example, when the user clicks a menu option, toolbar button, or presses an action's shortcut key combination, or when trigger() was called.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. I am still learning everything but now that works.